# Formula that Does NOT Contain 2 Different Texts

Tags: google-sheets

So I'm using Google sheets and I would like a cell to conditionally highlight when the cell does not have 2 specific texts.

[image]

So in my example, I would like cell B26 to highlight ONLY if it does **not** contain NYS or JFK.

Is that possible? It doesn't seem like there's a built in option in Google sheets.

A lot of guides only teach how to create custom formulae for texts that exist.
e.g., `=ISNUMBER(SEARCH("JFK",B26))`

I'm looking for the opposite effect.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In Conditional Formatting try with a custom formula like this:

```
=and (B8:B <> "JFK", B8:B <> "NYS" , B8:B <> "JFK/NYS" )
```

[image: do not highlight]

Comment: Don't think this is right. Try `=not(and (B8 <> "JFK", B8 <> "NYS" , B8 <> "JFK/NYS" ) )`

Comment: @Tedinoz Maybe you read the question too quickly ... your formula will highlight ALL cells containing JFK / NYS ... but OP wanted exactly the opposite i.e. all but those

Comment: You are zbsolutely right, I had left formula as-is, but my data was in Colum A. Argh.

Comment: This worked! Thank you so much!!!

Comment: So I tried the same thing for column C (but I replaced JFK & NYS with "1 Aug 2022" and "31 July 2022", and "B8:B to "C8:C"), changing the Apply to range field to C8 - but somehow it doesn't work. Is there a reason for this?

Comment: did you write the date in the correct way?   `=and (C8:C <> date(2022,8,1),C8:C <> date(2022,7,31))`   Also the range can't be only C8, but C8:C or something

Answer (score 1):

Have you tried checking the options under **Conditional Formatting**

You can add multiple rules to a single cell and apply the rules to other cells afterwards

[image]

Comment: What would you enter in the "Value or formula field"?

Comment: Tried this at first. Basically if I do this, the cell is highlighted if it doesn't have both NYS and JFK.